# inserting into json array in js/angularjs

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json array

```
var testArr=[{name:"name1",age:20},{name:"name1",age:20},{name:"name1",age:20}]
```

how do i insert an item "Uid"  into the testArr so that it looks like this

```
var testArr=[{name:"name1",age:20,uid:1},{name:"name1",age:20,uid:2},{name:"name1",age:20,uid:3}]
```

I have tried the following JS code but it seems to add it at the end

```
var testArr=[{name:"name1",age:20},{name:"name1",age:20},{name:"name1",age:20}];  
var loopCycle = (testArr.length);  
for(i=0; i < loopCycle ; i++){  
testArr.push({uID:i+1})
}    
console.log(testArr)
```

Thanks

Comment: `testArr[i]`. you are missing the index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
testArr.push({uID:i+1})
```

For each element in the array, you are creating a new element (`{uID:i+1}`). You need to access the JSON object and create a new property. Try this:

```
var testArr=[{name:"name1",age:20},{name:"name1",age:20},{name:"name1",age:20}];  
var loopCycle = (testArr.length);  
for(i=0; i < loopCycle ; i++){  
  testArr[i]['uid'] = i+1;
}    
console.log(testArr);
```

If you want to do it using the angular way, try this:

```
angular.forEach(testArr, function (x,idx) { x.uid = idx+1; });
```